# Finding a recursive formula for an increasing and bounded sequence

Tags: real-analysis

This is the original question: 
Find a recursive formula for the sequence $$\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}},\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{2}},...$$ Show that the sequence is increasing and bounded above by 4.
I have written a proof, but I am not sure if it is correct. Any feedback on whether it is right or not would be very helpful!

Recursive formula: $x_{1}={\sqrt{2}},
 x_{n+1}=\sqrt{2+x_{n}}$

My Proof: Using induction, we can see that the base case is $$x_{1}=2<\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}=x_{2},$$ so we just need to prove that $$x_{n}<x_{n+1} $$ implies that $$x_{n+1}<x_{n+2}.$$ But if $$x_{n}<x_{n+1} $$ then $${\sqrt{x_{n}}}<\sqrt{x_{n+1}}$$ and adding by 2 gives $$\sqrt{2+x_{n}}<\sqrt{2+x_{n+1}}.$$ Thus we have $$x_{n+1}<x_{n+2}$$ and the sequence is increasing. To show the sequence is bounded above by 4 we first observe that $$x_{1}<4.$$ Now if $$x_{n}<2,$$ then $$x_{n+1}=\sqrt{2+x_{n}}<\sqrt{2+\sqrt{4}}=2$$ as well, and $$x_{n}$$ is bounded. Therefore, this sequence converges by Monotone Convergence Theorem and we can assert that both $$x_{n}$$ and $$x_{n+1}$$ converge to some real number k. Taking limits across the recursive equation $$x_{n+1}=\sqrt{2+x_{n}}$$ yields $$k = \sqrt{2+k},$$ which implies $k=2+k$.

Comment: Your last lines are really strange.

Answer (score 1):

If you already know the sequence converges, say to $\;A\;$ , then by arithmetic of limits:

$$A\xleftarrow[\infty\leftarrow n]{} x_n=\sqrt{2+x_{n-1}}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\sqrt{2+A}\implies$$

$$A^2-A-2=0\iff (A-2)(A+1)=0\implies A=...$$

Answer (score 0):

Notice that if 
$$ a_{n+1} = \sqrt{2+a_n} $$
and $a_n=2\cos\theta$, we have $a_{n+1}=2\cos\frac{\theta}{2}$ by the cosine duplication formula.
In our case we have $x_1=2\cos\frac{\pi}{2\cdot 2^1}$ and $x_{n+1}=\sqrt{2+x_n}$, hence
$$ x_n = \color{red}{2\cdot\cos\frac{\pi}{2^{n+1}}} $$
and $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to +\infty}x_n = \color{red}{\large 2}.$ Since $\cos\theta$ is decreasing on the interval $\left[0,\frac{\pi}{4}\right]$,
 the sequence $\{x_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ is increasing and bounded by $2$.

Comment: Why the downvote?